# Where to put system cronjobs?

Tags: cron, upgrade

If I need a **cronjob that runs at system level** (i.e. not specific for a certain user) how do you suggest me to create it?

1. running `crontab -e` as root
2. appending it to `/etc/crontab`
3. creating a file defining the cronjob in `/etc/cron.d/`
4. creating a file defining the cronjob in `/etc/cron.*ly/` (but only if such time interval fits my needs)

What worries me mostly is: which of these solutions will be possibly **overwritten by a system update**?

Additionaly I guess that if the job is long I should put it on a **separate script file**, for instance in `/root/bin/`. Do you agree?

Comment: You should state what Unix or Linux distribution you use.

Comment: I'm just learning now :) I thought it was a distro-independent behaviour...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Don't use `crontab -e`

I wouldn't put it in `crontab -e` as root. This is generally less obvious to other admins and is likely to get lost over time. Putting them in `/etc/crontab` you can specify exactly the time that you want them to run and you can specify a different user as well.

#### Alternative locations

If you do not care about running the script as a different user, and/or you just want the script to run weekly, daily, etc. then several distributions provide directories where scripts can be placed that will automatically get processed at a specific time.

For example under Redhat based distros:

```
$ ls -dl /etc/cron*
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Nov 29 11:06 /etc/cron.d
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Nov 29 11:06 /etc/cron.daily
-rw-------. 1 root root    0 Nov 23 07:42 /etc/cron.deny
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Nov 29 11:03 /etc/cron.hourly
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Nov 29 11:06 /etc/cron.monthly
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  457 Sep 26  2011 /etc/crontab
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Sep 26  2011 /etc/cron.weekly
```

I'll often times put system level crons that I want to run at a specific time in `/etc/cron.d` instead of `/etc/crontab`, especially if they're more complex scripts.

I prefer using the directories under `/etc/cron*` because they're a much more obvious place that other system administrators will know to look and the files here can be managed via packages installations such as `rpm` and/or `apt`.

#### Protecting entries

Any of the directories I've mentioned are designated for putting scripts that will not get destroyed by a package manager. If you're concerned about protecting a crontab entry, then I would definitely not put it in the `/etc/crontab` file, and instead put it as a proper script in one of the `/etc/cron*` directories.

Comment: just a small question: you can simply put scrips into `/etc/cron.d` and it runs daily automatically or do you need to configure something else?

Answer (score 1):

I would choose #4. It lets the system settings choose when to run the job, and usually they do a good job of "run when not busy". Changing the system cron scheduler would also auto effect the run time of the script.

The down side is that you have no direct control over when it runs. If you need more direct control then use #1.

1 is least likely to get overwritten by a system update. Though 3 and 4 should be pretty safe. it all depends on how you update though. Your distro can update however it wants, but only 2, would typically be at risk of an overwrite.

Finally, I would put scripts in /usr/local/bin That's the "normal" place I put system wide things not managed by the distro's package manager. /root/bin is acceptable as well if it's only going to be run by root. However this is all mostly taste.

Answer (score 0):

Any of the above will work, and none of the above should be overwritten by updates. The actual choice comes down to opinion - any three different people will often have at least two if not three different answers.